# Insufficient funds v4.0 ethers.min.js

Tags: ethers.js, sendtransaction

When the sendTransaction is executed , it returns insufficient funds at Object.n [as throwError] (ethers.min.js:1)
    at ethers.min.js:1
    at tryCallOne (core.js:37)

```
import { Wallet, providers, getDefaultProvider } from "ethers";

transactionData={ to: "0xdfa7E6962d65870F34388E12fF1380e66c1F8c47"
 value: 1000000000000
 gasLimit: 21000
 gasPrice: 8000000000
 data: ""}

let wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, getDefaultProvider('mainnet'));
 wallet.sendTransaction(transactionData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your account](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdfa7E6962d65870F34388E12fF1380e66c1F8c47) holds 0.000068371576646932 ether, which is 68371576646932 wei.

With:

```
 value: 1000000000000
 gasLimit: 21000
 gasPrice: 8000000000
```

You tell the node that you are willing to spend at most `21000 * 8000000000 + 1000000000000` wei.

But since `21000 * 8000000000 + 1000000000000 = 169000000000000 > 68371576646932`, your transaction cannot be executed **even** if it would ultimately spend less than the amount that you've stated (which in this specific case it won't anyway, because you've set `gas: 21000`, which is the minimum possible for a transaction).

Comment: thanks ! that was silly of me to not check total cost .